# Transaction failed due to incorrectly calculated hash parameter in Payu when using User defined field

Tags: php, codeigniter, hash, payment-gateway, payu

I have integrated Payu with codeigniter website. Everything works fine when `udf1` field kept empty. when i tried to pass some parameter Transaction failed due to incorrectly calculated hash parameter.

```
$amount =  $orderdata[0]['ototal'];
    $product_info = $orderdata[0]['product_name'];
    $customer_name = $orderdata[0]['fname'];
    $customer_emial = $orderdata[0]['email'];
    $customer_mobile = $orderdata[0]['phone'];
    $customer_address = $orderdata[0]['address2'].$orderdata[0]['address1'];
    //payumoney details


        $MERCHANT_KEY = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"; //change  merchant with yours
        $SALT = "xxxxxxxxxx";  //change salt with yours 

        $txnid = substr(hash('sha256', mt_rand() . microtime()), 0, 20); 
        //optional udf values 
        $udf1 = $ord_id;
        $udf2 = '';
        $udf3 = '';
        $udf4 = '';
        $udf5 = '';

         $hashstring = $MERCHANT_KEY . '|' . $txnid . '|' . $amount . '|' . $product_info . '|' . $customer_name . '|' . $customer_emial . '|' . $udf1 . '|' . $udf2 . '|' . $udf3 . '|' . $udf4 . '|' . $udf5 . '||||||' . $SALT;
         $hash = strtolower(hash('sha512', $hashstring));
```

Comment: Did you solved the issue?

Comment: @Bergin yes, in my status controller section I forget to pass `$udf1` in `hashstring` generation

Comment: can you please tell me what is udf1,2,3...,10.

Comment: @Bergin they are user defined fields . which are not mandatory. here i have used `$udf1` to pass orderid to my success page.

Comment: yes I know those are user defined fields. But which type of data can be passed .. i mean JSON, array or only string.

Answer (score 0):

Should be pass  $udf1 in form like this

```
$email = "info@onlinefastag.in";
$productinfo = "New Fastag request";
$udf1 = $orderId;
$udf2 = "";
$udf3 = "";
$udf4 = "";
$udf5 = "";
<input name="udf1" input type= "hidden" value=" echo $udf1; "/>
```